# How to Prevent Line Connections Between Curves in Python Tkinter Plot Rendering?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a Python program for mathematic plot rendering using the Tkinter library to draw plots. My current issue is related to rendering curves, f.e tan(x). The problem is that when plotting these curves, they are being connected with lines that go from the last point of the previous tangent curve to the first point of the current one. This results in a plot that doesn't accurately represent the tangent curve.

Is there a way to prevent these unwanted line connections between tangent curves in Tkinter when rendering plots? I'd like the tangent curves to appear as smooth and continuous curves without any line segments connecting them.

Here's the part of my code that draws the plot:

```
def Calculate():
   
    global expression
    canvas.delete("graph")
    start = -25
    end = 25
    x_range = end - start

    prev_x = None
    prev_y = None
    rcolor = "#" + ("%06x" % random.randint(0, 16777215))
    for i in range(canvas.winfo_width()):
        x = (i / (canvas.winfo_width() - 1)) * x_range + start
        try:
            y = eval(expression)
        except ValueError or ZeroDivisionError or TypeError:
            continue


        canvas_x = i
        canvas_y = canvas.winfo_height() - (y - start) / x_range * canvas.winfo_height()

        if prev_x is not None and prev_y is not None and prev_x is not canvas_x:
            canvas.create_line(prev_x, prev_y, canvas_x, canvas_y, tags="graph", fill=rcolor, width=1.5)

        prev_x = canvas_x
        prev_y = canvas_y
```

I really have no idea on how to fix this, but i tried to make the line to be drawn while canvas_x == prev_x. Didn't work